# sql query with AND and OR

Tags: sql, delphi

EDIT..sorry 
columns are strings
db is mysql i belive.

I am trying to do a query but not sure how to write it,  currently i have

```
   adoquery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM workorder WHERE siteid=''p203'' AND worktype = ''CM'' AND reportdate > '''+edit1.text+'''') ;
```

which gets data with the date grader then the date in edit1.text, how can i make it say to get the same data but with reportdate between two dates?

example

```
siteid = p203   AND
worktype = CM   AND
reportdate between edit1.text and edit2.text
```

Comment: Database engine and column types, please...

Comment: exactly as you did for `>` ? Just check if BETWEEN exist in your dbms, and how it works. You can also use `and reportdate >={text1} AND reportdate < {text2}`

Comment: You've got the classic SQL injection vulnerability here

Comment: As @David said: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: its for personal use only anyhow

Comment: @GlenMorse: see it as a good coding practice, ALWAYS use parameters, even if it's for "quick and dirty" apps. Chances are big that you leak this bad practice into security sensitive code...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many databases have a BETWEEN operator, otherwise you can always use `(reportdate >= :date1 and reportdate <= :date2)`.

```
SELECT * FROM workorder 
WHERE siteid = :siteId AND worktype = :workType
AND reportdate between :date1 and :date2
```

Or,

```
SELECT * FROM workorder 
WHERE siteid = :siteId AND worktype = :workType
AND (reportdate >= :date1 and reportdate <= :date2)
```

*The second form gives you a little bit more control over whether you use closed-open (inclusive at the start) or closed (inclusive at both ends) bounds.*

Ideally, you'd use *bound parameters* -- using a :name placeholder for each parameter in your statement, and binding values to them. (In other languages we use ?).

As well as preventing SQL injection hacks & bugs with quoting, this can also be more reliable with `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` datatypes. Dates should be properly parsed & strings should be converted to such at the application layer, rather than stored as strings in the DB.

Comment: . . Pretty much all databases have `between`.  It is ANSI standard.

Comment: Delphi normally uses :ParamName rather than ? for parameter substitution.

Answer (score 7):

```
adoquery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM workorder'); 
adoquery1.SQL.Add('WHERE siteid=:SiteId AND'); 
adoquery1.SQL.Add('worktype = :WorkType AND'); 
adoquery1.SQL.Add('reportdate between :StartDate and :EndDate ');

adoquery1.Parameters[0].Value := 'p203';
adoquery1.Parameters[1].Value := 'CN';
adoquery1.Parameters[2].Value := Edit1.Text;
adoquery1.Parameters[3].Value := Edit2.Text;
```

The point of this code fragment is that it is just as easy to solve the problem using parameters as it is to 'inline' your Sql.

The main benefit is that your data are sanitised automatically with 2 effects - i) you are protected against Sql injection attacks and ii) you dont have to perform preprocessing on the data - e.g if Surname were "O'Flannagan" passing that as an inline value requires a preprocessing function e.g. `RemoveApostrophes()`.

There is an additional benefit on servers such as Oracle - the Oracle optimiser will cache a query plan.  If it encounters the same Sql it will use the cached plan, and thus perform better.  It can identify parameters as being 'Same', but cannot if you provide a different Sql each time.  (I cannot particularly comment on other RDBMSs but I would not be surprised if the same applied.)

In my view this approach is at least as readable as the other.

Comment: How about some text to explain this?

Comment: @david - done.  I don't think I could bear to answer this same question again, though ;)  (I see you have a fan)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan even i would not of done that to you. Thanks for answer btw